# Input element with file type does not work in chrome - Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an Angular 2 app. Please see a part of template below -

```
     <label class="import-label" title="Select file">
          <span class="grid-btn fa fa-folder">
             <input type="file" class="form-control import-input-file" id="contactname" aria-describedby="contactname" 
              placeholder="File Name" name="filename" style="display:none;"
             (change)="onChange($event)">
           </span>
    </label>
```

**Screenshot** -

[image]

When I click on the folder icon button, dialog for selecting a file does not get open up in Chrome(It works for IE as expected). It, however, works on a double click in Chrome.

**Note** :

The `input tag` has `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

add **for="contactname"** to the label

```
<label class="import-label" title="Select file" for="contactname">
```

Comment: Thanks @domfx. It still does not work with "for" attribute. I have found other solution though. Setting display:none was the problem. I have now used opacity:0; It works now!